# Canon MP510 pixma: "The type of print head is incorrect"

Tags: printer, canon-pixma

After printing a few pages, my Canon MP510 shows this message on its display:

> The type of print head is incorrect. Install the correct print head.

Now the printer doesn't print anything and doesn't even allow to scan(!).

I tried:

- unplugging the printer, waiting 10 minutes, turning it on again
- removing and re-inserting the cartridges and the print head
- cleaning the contacts of the printhead and the contacts in the
  printhead holder
- resetting the printer by holding the stop button while the printer is booting up and then pressing Stop 5 times before releasing the Power button.

None of this worked.

Is there any solution?